# Удалить все cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Существует множество кукисов вида: `$.cookie('cookie_' + id, 'cookie_value');`. Известно, что удалить кукис можно так: `$.cookie('cookie_' + id, null);`. Однако id множество и известен id только в контексте функции (также записан в cookies). Как удалить все такие кукисы, кроме как функцией:

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
    var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
}
```

Comment: Так вам надо удалить все кукисы или определённые?

Comment: Которые имеют вид `$.cookie('cookie_' + id, 'cookie_value');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю вы используете плагин `jquery-cookie`. Вызов `$.cookie();` вернет все куки в виде объекта. И в плагине уже есть метод для удаления кукиса по имени.

```
function removeAllCookie() {
    const cookie = $.cookie(); // все кукисы

    for (let i in cookie) {
        $.removeCookie(i);
    }
}

removeAllCookie();
```